# Why is pidof not working?

Tags: process, pidof

In the output of `ps aux`, I can see the process just fine:

```
# ps aux | grep diff
root      7787 28.7  0.0   9368  4516 pts/3    D+   13:56  20:33 diff -qr mnt/mnt/md/ mnt/mnt2/
root     13130  0.0  0.0   6144   876 pts/4    S+   15:07   0:00 grep diff
```

But `pidof` claims not to be able to find anything:

```
# pidof diff
# echo $?
1
```

Looking at the man page, there is no info on what to do when lost a process, pidof has. `/proc/7787/exe` is a symlink to `/usr/bin/diff` and `/usr/bin/diff` itself is a regular file and an ELF. According to the man page, this ought to match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In sysvinit 2.96 and later, `pidof -z` will include processes that are in disk I/O ('D') or zombie ('Z') state.

Comment: Thanks! I checked out some more info, here are links for others that are interested: [commit that introduced the problem (Oct 2018)](http://git.savannah.nongnu.org/cgit/sysvinit.git/commit/src/killall5.c?id=1b659c8ebebd86be51095ab905293889a306ff01) | [sysvinit-utils bug report (Jun 2019)](https://savannah.nongnu.org/bugs/?56534) | [debian bug thread about the problem (Apr 2019--Oct 2021)](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=926896)

Comment: Thanks for this info. It seems that whoever changed the behaviour of `pidof` has made quite a mess of backwards-incompatibility.

Answer (score 6):

After some investigation with `strace`, it seems that `pidof` also checks the status of the processes. My `diff` process was in `D` state most of the time, meaning it is waiting for I/O a lot. With this knowledge, I ran `pidof` a bunch of times (this is within ~3 seconds):

```
# pidof diff
7787
# pidof diff
# pidof diff
7787
# pidof diff
# pidof diff
# pidof diff
# pidof diff
# pidof diff
# pidof diff
# pidof diff
# pidof diff
# pidof diff
# pidof diff
7787
# pidof diff
7787
```

It indeed returns it 'sometimes', seeming to confirm the suspicion that `pidof` only return processes that are not in `D` state.

Checking the source code of `pidof` in `src/killall5.c` (obtained using `apt source sysvinit-utils`), the answer lies on line 599:

```
if ( (strchr(process_status, 'D') != NULL) ||
     (strchr(process_status, 'Z') != NULL) ){
   /* Ignore zombie processes or processes in
      disk sleep, as attempts
      to access the stats of these will
      sometimes fail. */
```

Comment: So rather than sometimes failing, they elect to always fail on processes in those states. And `pidof` doesn't use any stats anyway, just shows the process ID. It can surely check the process ID and exe name, in fact this little shell command does it:
`ls -l /proc/*/exe 2>/dev/null | grep "/$WHAT$"`  Am I missing something?  I'd like to do a git blame on this one and ask them a few pointed questions.

Comment: @SamWatkins By all means! I see it the same way.